# Setup Gulp watch to run only when file is saved

Tags: javascript, gulp, visual-studio-code, gulp-watch

I have working gulpfille but the only problem is, when I'm editing .ts files or html files every time I write a single letter the watch function fires and it reload my browser constantly as I type.

Is there a way I can setup gulp to run task on save?

```
// Watch
gulp.task('watch', ['typescript', 'sass', 'browserSync'], () => {
  gulp.watch('./app/scripts/**/*.ts', ['typescript']);
  gulp.watch('./app/styles/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('./app/index.html', browserSync.reload);
});
```

**EDIT**

Fixed by setting "files.autoSave" to "off" in VS Code.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS Code

Comment: Did you modify "files.autoSave" on vscode?. Set it to "off"

Comment: I had it on "afterDelay" but looks like, "off" fixed it, thank you!